# Search keyword from Dbpedia using nodejs

Tags: node.js, rdf, semantic-web, semantics, dbpedia

I am new in node.js.I downloaded and executed a project from GitHub from this [link](https://github.com/hvarg/RDFExplorer). Here on this [link](http://RDFExplorer.org) there is live demo of this app. It is running rdf search using wikidata. This is the function that I found for the search of keyword from wikidata written in file public/scripts/controllers/main.js.

```
 function search () {
    //TODO: fix when null;
    if (vm.searchInput != vm.lastSearch) {
      var input = vm.searchInput;
      vm.lastSearch = input;
      vm.searchWait = true;
      vm.noResults  = false;
      //$http.get('https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&limit=20&uselang=en&type=item&continue=0&search='+input).then(
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php',
        params: {
          action: 'wbsearchentities',
          format: 'json',
          language: 'en',
          uselang: 'en',
          type: 'item',
          continue: '0',
          limit: '20',
          search: input,
          origin: '*',
        }
      }).then(
        function onSuccess (response) {
          onSearch(response.data.search);
        },
        function onError (response) { onSearchErr(); console.log('Error: ' + response.data); }
      );
      //request.execQuery(query.search(input), onSearch, onSearchErr);
    }
    vm.searchActive = true;
  }
```

I have changed the above function for DBpedia but it not search the keyword from DBpedia

```
  function search2 () {
    //TODO: fix when null;
    if (vm.searchInput != vm.lastSearch) {
      var input = vm.searchInput;
      vm.lastSearch = input;
      vm.searchWait = true;
      vm.noResults  = false;
      //$http.get('https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&limit=20&uselang=en&type=item&continue=0&search='+input).then(
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql',
        params: {
          action: 'wbsearchentities',
          format: 'json',
          language: 'en',
          uselang: 'en',
          type: 'item',
          continue: '0',
          limit: '20',
          search: input,
          origin: '*',
        }
      }).then(
        function onSuccess (response) {
          onSearch(response.data.search);
        },
        function onError (response) { onSearchErr(); console.log('Error: ' + response.data); }
      );
      //request.execQuery(query.search(input), onSearch, onSearchErr);
    }
    vm.searchActive = true;
  }
```

how I can change this above function for search in DBpedia?Please help

Comment: ehm, DBpedia is **not** Wikidata ... in your first snippet you're using a Wikidata REST API service for entity lookup, in particular the `wbsearchentities` service. The DBpedia SPARQL endpoint in your second code snippet is ... just a SPARQL endpoint. You have to write and send a SPARQL query

Comment: just as a minor hint (I will not rewrite your Javascript code) - a query you can use is `select distinct ?s {
?s rdfs:label ?l .
FILTER(langmatches(lang(?l), 'en'))
?l bif:contains "here_your_input_token"
} limit 20` - your task is to find and use a Javascript SPARQL API or just use plain HTTP request (`query` param is the way to go)

Comment: what is Javascript SPARQL API for DBpedia?